# border color white issue

Tags: css, html

I have two divs that are right above each other. The bottom one has border-top-color:white.

The problem with this is that, on the left side, the left black borders line up for both of them so it is one straight black line but on the right side, the border color white creates a little white space between the right side border so it is not straight like that in the left side.

I appreciate your help.

---

Here is the code I have:

```
border:1px solid black;
border-top-color:white;
```

Here is it on JSFiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/zu4p8/

Please help me.

Comment: Could you post an example of your markup to [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net)? Preferably the smallest amount of code that produces your problem.

Comment: Perhaps a screenshot would make things a little more clear?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The fact that just seem to happen has been taken to the top width of the left white line. You should know you see it zoom.

try this

change

```
border-top-color:white;
```

to

```
border-top-style:none;
```